# Compare Lists In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I need to compare two lists in Excel.  The format is like so:

```
ID  Amt      ID  AMT
12  35       12  53
14  63       18  22
88  33       24  55
```

The lists before had been matching up exactly with ID's so I would just simply use the `=` function and say

```
A1=D1 
B1=E1
```

However, as you can see now the #'s vary.  What is the quickest, most efficient way for me to compare these two lists?  What I need done is:

> 1) From the list on the right find the id in the list on the left
>   
> 2) Verify the amt from the list on the right matches the list on the left
>   
> 3) If it matches, do nothing, if it does not change the fill on the list on the right to red.

**EDIT**
I tried to use the `VLOOKUP()` function and this was the criteria I set:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,E2:F571,2,TRUE)
```

Now let me explain, A2 holds the ID I want to locate in E2 and F# would hold the value I want to compare to the value from A# so I set the next value to 2.

I used TRUE as I only want an exact match, but when used this produces a #N/A on all of my rows.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and where you have run into problems. This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with code you are trying to develop. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Use conditional formatting with a condition formula which involves `vlookup`

Comment: See Edit --- I tried VLOOKUP() and it returns #N/A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your post, D holds the ID and E holds the amount, so it should be:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,D2:E571,2,TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things I can think of.

1) In VLookup TRUE as the 4th argument will do an approximate match - not exact match (see [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)).

2) Not sure why you'd be getting #N/A in every row - you might want to look at absolute references (ie $E$2:$F$571 vs E2:F571), especially if you are filling the formula down. [This](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9) will help explain.